# Firebase Firestore return QuerySnapshot

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I just started to play with the firebase cloud function and firestore but when I'm using firestore inside the firebase cloud function (as below code) it's return and QuerySnapshot instead of return data. If anyone has got this issue before and solved it already then tell me. It would help me to resolve this issue too.

Thanks.

```
export async function allRestaurants(req: Request, res: Response) {
  try {
    // const { id } = req.params
    const restaurantsRef = admin.firestore().collection('restaurants');
    const snapshot = await restaurantsRef.get();

    console.log(">>>>>>>>>", snapshot);
    return res.status(200).send({ data: { restaurants: snapshot } })
  } catch (err) {
    return handleError(res, err)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is normal that you get a [`QuerySnapshot`](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/QuerySnapshot.html), since the [`get()`](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/CollectionReference.html#get) method returns a Promise that resolves with a `QuerySnapshot`.

It's up to you to generate the content you want to send back to the Cloud Function consumer.

For example, you can use the [`forEach()`](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/QuerySnapshot.html#forEach) method to loop over the `QuerySnapshot`, or, as shown below, use the [`docs`](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/QuerySnapshot.html#docs) array.

```
export async function allRestaurants(req: Request, res: Response) {
  try {
    // const { id } = req.params
    const restaurantsRef = admin.firestore().collection('restaurants');
    const snapshot = await restaurantsRef.get();

    const responseContent = snapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data());

    return res.status(200).send({ data: { restaurants: responseContent } })
  } catch (err) {
    return handleError(res, err)
  }
}
```